# How do I add future dates to table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a schedule in rails and I need to  see if today's date matches the date of an event in the future. I have an event model with a date field and I know the dates of all the future events, but how do I add those dates to the table in a way rails will understand?

I'd like to do something like:

```
if Time.now is equal to next event
  # do this
```

Time.now outputs

```
2014-03-18 11:05:14 -0500
```

How do I add that sort of format to the dates in the table so that I can compare Time.now to the date of the future event?

**EDIT**

Say I'm creating a new Event in the rails console, And I want the date of the Event to be April 1, 2014. I'm trying to figure out what syntax I need to enter the date in the console. For example, to create an Event in console I would do something like

```
Event.create(name: "Event1", date: ??)
```

What do I put in place of the question marks for the date of April 1, 2014 in syntax understood by the computer? I need April 1, 2014 in a datetime format, not a string.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seeds.rb` is—as the file extension implies—just Ruby.

You can supply the date in any form that an available Ruby library can parse into a `Time` or `Date` object.

If you want to keep it human-readable, you can use `Date.parse`:

```
Event.create(name: 'Event1', date: Date.parse('Apr 1 2014'))
Event.create(name: 'Event2', date: Date.parse('April 1, 2014'))
Event.create(name: 'Event3', date: Date.parse('1-Apr-14'))
```

Or, if you need human-readable times as well, `Time.parse`:

```
Event.create(name: 'Event4', date: Time.parse('09:15 1 Apr 2014'))
Event.create(name: 'Event5', date: Time.parse('April 1, 2014, 9:15am'))
Event.create(name: 'Event6', date: Time.parse('1-Apr-14, 09:15 -0700'))
```

If you prefer to use UNIX timestamps, `Time.at` creates a new `Time` object from them (and offers a mild performance benefit over parsing textual dates):

```
Event.create(name: 'Event7', date: Time.at(1395166977))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have defined `next_event` as a `datetime` column in database, rails will automatically initialize it as a `date_time` object when you load it from database. All you need is this

```
if Time.now.to_date == next_event.to_date
```

For adding the future days, you can use `days.from_now` method

For eg

```
1.days.from_now #Wed, 19 Mar 2014 16:29:26 UTC +00:00
2.days_from_now #Thu, 20 Mar 2014 16:30:16 UTC +00:00
```

Or you can use normal addition

```
Time.now + 2.days
Time.now + 2.hours
Time.now + 10.minutes

Event.create(name: "Event1", date: (Time.now + 1.day))
```

Comment: Right, but I'm loading all the events via a seeds file, so what syntax would I for `Game.create(date: ??)`

Comment: @reknirt: I am not sure if I understand what you are asking for. But let me know if my edit answers your question